# What happens in the backend when you initialize a variable on the stack in C?

Tags: c, heap-memory

When I declare a variable `int b;` what actually happens in the backend? Would it translate to `int* b = malloc(sizeof(int))`, just that it will be bound by a scope? I understand that a variable on the stack is bound by a scope and the heap is not necessarily bound by a scope, but on the backend, is the allocation similar? Hopefully I explained it well enough for someone to correct me

Comment: No, `malloc` is allocating memory on the heap.  What you'd get on the stack is just a reservation on the stack that can contain that value.  Or, you might not get anything at all.  The compiler is free to use registers for stack variables if it wants to.

Comment: No it does not translate to that. Stack and heap allocation are two different things, one is not simply a translation for another.

Comment: In that case, how does the program create a space on the stack when we initialize a variable?

Comment: It uses the stack pointer, usually (if it needs the stack at all).  _e.g._ https://godbolt.org/z/TEfKTM3P6

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most CPUs have a register that functions as a "stack pointer" for the running thread; it always points to the "top" of the thread's stack.  Whenever a new stack object needs to be created, the object is initialized at the address the stack-pointer is currently pointing to, and then the stack-pointer's value is increased by the size of the object.

Similarly, after a stack-object has been destroyed (because execution is leaving the current scope), the stack-pointer is decreased by the size of the object.

That's really all there is to it; it's much simpler and more efficient than manipulating the heap.  The only downside is that space has to be initialized and de-initialized in strict FILO order -- i.e. objects have to be destroyed in the opposite order from how they were constructed.